# ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with two tables.
This is the layout of the table:

**tbl_country**

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| countryID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| country   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**tbl_spots**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| location    | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| geocode     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| added_date  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| countryID   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I tried to join the two tables with the following command so that the two tables are connected with countryID.

```
select tbl_spots.id, tbl_spots.description, tbl_spots.geocode, tbl_spots.added_date 
from tbl_spots 
inner join tbl_spots on tbl_spots.countryID=tbl_country.countryID;
```

After executing the command I get the following error:

> ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_spots'

Comment: Did you mean to write `inner join tbl_county` instead of `inner join tbl_spots`?

Comment: Why JOIN tbl_county, when you don't select any of its columns?

Comment: @jarlh This is to only pull back rows that have matching CountryIDs. If something exists in the first table but the Country ID doesn't exist, it won't show. Check out [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)  for a good explaination :)

Comment: @Tehcheatah, countryID is NOT NULL, i.e. no country-free should exist - at least if the datatabase is properly set up with foreign keys.

Comment: @jarlh Good Spot. Completely missed that you are correct. My Bad

Answer (score 1):

```
from tbl_spots 
inner join tbl_spots on tbl_spots.countryID=tbl_county.countryID;
```

I guess, it is a typo

Answer (score 1):

You are inner joining the table to itself. Please see the below

```
SELECT tbl_spots.id
      ,tbl_spots.description
      ,tbl_spots.geocode
      ,tbl_spots.added_date
FROM tbl_spots 
INNER JOIN tbl_country
ON tbl_spots.countryID = tbl_country.countryID
```

You were trying to reference a table that you aren't actually pulling through